# To prove the fiber above a codimension 1 point contains a geometrically integral open subscheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}_k^n$ is a proper smooth morphism, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. If $f$ admits a rational section, can we prove that the fiber of $f$ above any codimension 1 point contains a geometrically integral open subscheme?

Comment: The conclusion also holds under the weaker assumption that $f: X \to \mathbb{P}^n_k$ is a proper morphism with $X$ regular. This is because as $X$ is regular, the image of any rational section must lie in the smooth locus of $f$. Then you apply R. van Dobben de Bruyn's answer to the smooth locus of $f$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is true:

Because $f$ is smooth, any fibre $X_y$ is smooth. If $y$ has codimension $1$, then the rational section $\sigma \colon \mathbb P^n_k \dashrightarrow X$ is defined at $y$ by the valuative criterion of properness. Thus, $X_y$ has a rational point $\sigma(y)$. If $U \subseteq X_y$ is the connected component of $\sigma(y)$, then $U$ is a smooth connected $\kappa(y)$-scheme with a rational point, hence geometrically connected by [Tag 04KV](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04KV).